# Microsoft.AspNet.Session not available in ASP.NET core 1.0 rc1 update2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We are working on an application with asp.net core 1.0. Recently I need to use a session in asp.net core 1.0 Web Api application.

I have found a good article from the following link 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0

But when I put Microsoft.AspNet.Session package in project.json at that time it's saying that package is no available. From where I can find the package for the session.

Comment: Please show us your project.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command to install Nuget package from nuget console in Visual studio:

```
  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Session -Pre
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a nuget package you can get it from here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Session/